# How to develop on windows using C++ and CMake

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

Question is - how to develop on Windows platform with comfort, using CMake as primary configuration tool.  What I mean is IDE or something, that parse CMake config and help you to include external hpp files for example. I know that Qt Creator can (it support MSVC compiler), but Qt Creator sometimes fail to save file with error "Can't write to disk. Is it full". Seems like bug. And that's all.
What I mean is not generate .sln for Visual Studio.
Also I tried VS 2017 RC, but its crashing constantly with my project.
P.S. I tried Visual Studio with separate .sln, but it's really uncomfortably to support two different configs.
Thanks

Comment: On Windows, Cmake as a graphic editor.

Comment: the question is too generic to be answered, you will get vague answers too. Lot of developers have used both MSVS and QTCreator successfully with CMake. Using MSVS and not wanting to use a solution is counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: you could try clion from jetbrains (https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/). CLion is an nice and comfortable IDE and supports exclusively cmake-files

Comment: Yes, thanks. I use clion as linux ide, but on windows its not support msvc :(

Comment: Did you try older versions of MSVS ? Should also work with 2013 and 2015

Comment: They cant parse CMake as 2017 RC

Comment: MSVC support for Clion will be available this year. It is on their road map.

Comment: Yeah I saw, to be honest, this is awesome news. But this year just started, so it's pretty long to wait :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out [KDevelop 5 for Windows](https://www.kdevelop.org/), it has great CMake support, as well as Clang based language features.